# How do I write a script to find tables dependencies across schemas?

Tags: oracle11g

I am painfully new to Oracle after coming from a SQL Server Background. Here is my question:

There are two schemas that I am interested in: `ABC_OWNER` and `XYZ_OWNER`.

What I want to find out is all of the references to tables in `XYZ_OWNER` schema within the `ABC_OWNER` schema. This is mostly for stored procedures. The query would return a list of all the tables and columns that are referenced in `XYZ_OWNER` by `ABC_OWNER`. I have tried running a few queries that I found on SO but I am running into issues as the account that I am logged in as does not have access to DBA tables.

The reason I am doing this is because I am planning to remove `XYZ_OWNER` tables and plug in a new database. I want to see what columns I will need in my new database and whether or not they exist.

Comment: Take a look at the public_dependency view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I trapped the query that TOAD executes when looking for dependencies on an object.  A slimmed-down version you could adapt looks like:

```
    SELECT uo1.object_name
      FROM (SELECT object_id, referenced_object_id
              FROM public_dependency
             WHERE referenced_object_id <> object_id) pd,
           all_objects uo1
     WHERE uo1.object_id = pd.object_id
CONNECT BY PRIOR pd.object_id = pd.referenced_object_id
START WITH pd.referenced_object_id IN (SELECT object_id
                                         FROM all_objects
                                        WHERE     object_name = <your table>
                                              AND owner = <your schema name> )
```

You will need access granted to the all_objects and public_dependency views if you don't have that.

Comment: Thank you for this query. I saw something weird where there were objects referenced that were not in all_objects table. I created a separate question for it here in case you have any more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541307/how-can-public-dependency-contain-references-to-objects-not-in-all-objects