# How can public_dependency contain references to objects not in all_objects?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have the query below:

```
select * from public_dependency  pd 
where REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID = 305318
```

The strange thing is that this returns 26 rows. When I join in the referenced objects, I get three null rows, but a count of 26. And if I use 'join' I get back 23 rows. So there are objects seemingly not in `all_objects` but in `public_dependency`.

```
select * from public_dependency  pd 
left join all_objects o on o.OBJECT_ID = pd.OBJECT_ID
where REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID = 305318
```

How is it possible that there are objects in `public_dependency` that are not in `all_objects`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all_objects` only shows you objects you have permissions on, not all objects in the database. You'd need to query `dba_objects` to see everything, if you have permissions to do that.

`public_dependency` appears to include object IDs for objects you don't have permissions on. The objecct IDs on their own don't tell you much, so it isn't revealing anything about objects you can't see (other than that there are some objects you can't see).

So it isn't odd that there is an apparent discrepancy between what the two views reference. Querying `all_dependencies` might give you a more comsistent picture.